# Entering conditional formula regarding a persons DOB in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am a complete novice at using formula in excel so I apologise for my ignorance in advance. I work for a tennis club and I am inputting our junior players' data into a spreadsheet in order to identify players who meet specific parameters.

The parameters help determine what colour tournaments he/she will play.

Example: the tournament calender for players is split into two seasons, the winter season (01/09 - 31/03) and the summer season (01/04 - 31/08)

there are 5 groups a player progresses through as they get older: Red ball (8 or under), Orange (age 9), green (age 10) yellow 12 (12 - 11) yellow 14 (14-13)

Josh is born 01/01/2005 is 9 years old and so is an Orange player. However, his date of birth falls within the current winter season - he will turn 10 before 01/04/2015 so he must now play in green tournaments.

In a spreadsheet I want one column titled 'colour' that identifies what colour player he is based on his age. I want a second column 'tournament' that identifies him as having to play 'green' because is DOB falls with the current season

I have tried to work it out myself but because Im so unfamiliar with using formula in spreadsheets and because there are so many conditions I am getting very confused. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: First you need to set a field with the players age on it. And then you have to set conditional formatting for each age boundary you specify.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what I would suggest.

In A1:G1 put some headings e.g.

Season End, Player, Dob, Age, Tournament Age, Colour, Tournament

In A2:E2 put in some data and formulae:-

31/3/15, Josh, 1/2/05, =DATEDIF(C2,TODAY(),"y"), =DATEDIF(C2,$A$2,"y")

(31/3/15 is the end of the current season).

Leave A3 blank and fill in some more data in B3 and C3, and pull the formulae in D2 and E2 down.

Continue with as many rows as you need.

Then select the range you eventually want for all the colours in column F and start to build up the conditional formatting. The rules you need are in

Conditional formatting | New Rule  | Use a formula | Format values where this value is true,
then enter the formula, press format button and select fill colour.

=d2<9   red fill colour

=d2<10  orange fill colour

and so on.

At the end you need to select the range again and go in to 'Manage Rules' and check that the rules are in the right order and tick the 'stop if true' boxes.

Finally once the Colours are working the easiest thing is to use the format painter to copy the formats from column F to column G for the Tournament formats. This will automatically change =d2<9 etc. above to =e2<9 etc. so the formatting is based on the Tournament age.

It will probably take some trial and error to get it right!